Speed strip not working when rendering video?
I am using the blender video editor, I'm brand new to it. I have applied a speed strip to my video to slow it down, and when I view it in the editor window, it is indeed slowed down. However, when I render the video, the speed strip is seemingly not applied properly. What am I doing wrong?

